# sqlmap syntax don't ask any question during work

Tags: linux, sqlmap, kali-linux

I'm using python to execute another sqlmap syntax and get response and log it in one file but during sqlmap run ask many question about params or ... but only i need simple and fast answer about my url have any hole or no if have it , give me report of that...

I use syntax like that:

```
sqlmap -u "url string"
```

Upper syntax ask many question about details during scan but I need simple report without question...

Do you know any flag syntax or anything that check it without ask any question with fine level of testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
--answers="follow=Y" --batch
```

From SQLmap wiki:

> Act in non-interactive mode Switch: --batch
>
> If you want sqlmap to run as a batch tool, without any user's interaction when sqlmap requires it, you can force that by using switch --batch. This will leave sqlmap to go with a default behaviour whenever user's input would be required.
>
> Set answers for questions Option: --answers
>
> In case that user wants to automatically set up answers for questions, even if --batch is used, using this option he can do it by providing any part of question together with answer after an equal sign. Also, answers for different question can be split with delimiter character ,.

Answer (score 0):

You can use --batch flag. This will automate the process for sure. However, It will be at the cost of the efficiency of the attack in case you need to tweak it at some point.